# String intern() behaviour

Tags: java, string, string-interning

From the [javaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) of String class's intern method :

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object)
>   method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this
>   String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String
>   object is returned.

Consider the following use-cases:

```
    String first = "Hello";
    String second = "Hello";

    System.out.println(first == second);

    String third = new String("Hello");
    String fourth = new String("Hello");

    System.out.println(third == fourth);

    System.out.println(third == fourth.intern());
    System.out.println(third.intern() == fourth);
    System.out.println(third == fourth);

    System.out.println(third.intern() == fourth.intern());
    System.out.println(third.intern() == first);

    String fifth = new String(new char[]{'H','e','l', 'l', 'o'});
    String sixth = new String(new char[]{'H','e','l', 'l', 'o'});

    System.out.println(fifth == fifth.intern());
    System.out.println(sixth == sixth.intern());

    String seven = new String(new char[]{'H','e','l', 'l', 'o' , '2'});
    String eight = new String(new char[]{'H','e','l', 'l', 'o' , '2'});

    System.out.println(seven == seven.intern());
    System.out.println(eight == eight.intern());
```

Can someone please explain why **`seven == seven.intern()`** is **true** whereas the following are **false**:

- `System.out.println(fifth == fifth.intern());`
- `System.out.println(sixth == sixth.intern());`
- `System.out.println(eight == eight.intern());`

Comment: What do you not get? With `fifth`, `sixth`, and `eight`, the string pool already contains an equal string. With `seven`, it doesn't.

Comment: Obvious question... Why do you care?

Comment: Because he doesn't want to uselessly waste memory?

Comment: If the String pool does not contain an equal String then as per the javaDoc it is added to the pool. But how come the 'seven == seven.intern()' returns true, i.e. how come the newly inserted String satisfies the == opertator with **seven** which for others does not holds true? ex: fifth == fifth.intern() returns false

Comment: @pczeus in 2016? That is a non argument. Also, consider the cost of "interning" string instances; that is basically real time, memory contents deduplication, done in userland. Java has far more serious problems with lower level memory access (cache misses, etc) than `.intern()`.

Comment: Agreed @fge. With that said, Details like this, I consider a matter of 'chipping away` at good coding practices, which add up over time as technical debt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seven is the first time you use the string 'hello2'. Therefor what the `intern` does is insert your string to the pool (and also return it). there for it is equal to your seven.

when you work with eight, the string is already in the pool (by running `seven.intern()` before, therefor when you do `eight == eight.intern()` you will get on the left side of the equation the newly created `eight` string, and on the right side the string created by seven from the pool, which are not the same

Comment: Just a small doubt, we say that intern "inserts the string to the pool", Can you please explain this statement. What does it actually inserts in the pool : the actual String or the reference that is pointing to it?

In other words is it correct to say that String Pool is a collection of References or the collection of actual Objects? As you mentioned eight == eight.intern() will be having String returned by seven.intern() on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use the `new String()` syntax, you are not taking advantage of the String pool, but creating a new instance of String regardless of whether it is in the pool or not.

Moral of the story.. NEVER use `new String()`

You are at the mercy of the JVM, which has the choice of making the decision of whether or not an 'internalized' String already exists, or should be internalized.
More specifically:

> To derive a string literal, the Java Virtual Machine examines the sequence of code points given by the CONSTANT_String_info structure.
>
> If the method String.intern has previously been called on an instance of class String containing a sequence of Unicode code points identical to that given by the CONSTANT_String_info structure, then the result of string literal derivation is a reference to that same instance of class String.
> Otherwise, a new instance of class String is created containing the sequence of Unicode code points given by the CONSTANT_String_info structure; a reference to that class instance is the result of string literal derivation. Finally, the intern method of the new String instance is invoked.

Comment: Then why System.out.println(fifth == fifth.intern()); returns false ?

Answer (score 0):

pczeus is correct.  More info:

fifth is a new string (pool was not checked) that contains the value "Hello".  When you intern() it, the return value is fourth (first occurrence of "Hello" being interned), which does not equal fifth.

Same answer for sixth.

seven is the first occurrence of "Hello2" and it does not get interned until you call 'seven == seven.intern()'.  Since it gets interned at that moment the return value of intern() is seven.

eight is another new instance of "Hello2".  When it gets interned, the return value is seven, which is not eight

Answer (score 0):

```
  String seven = new String(new char[]{'H','e','l', 'l', 'o' , '2'});
```

The literal "`Hello2`" will cause an object in the string constant pool to be created. The new String will create a new String object on the heap, with a copy of the content of the object for the literal.

You should never create String object like that, because it's unnecessary and inefficient. When you do `System.out.println(seven == seven.intern());` it will print `true`.

Now when you do `System.out.println(eight == eight.intern());` the string is returned from the string pool as it is already present, hence it will print `false`.